# How to transliterate english characters into malayalamletters?

Tags: php

I need malayalam  word corresponding to the english word typed in a text box 
like

saaaa ->സാആആആആ

Answer (score 0):

So you only need to replace the letters? No real translating? In that case I guess this will do

```
$english_string = 'abc';

$search = array();
$search[] = 'a';
$search[] = 'b';
$search[] = 'c';

$replace = array();
$replace[] = 'സാ';
$replace[] = 'ആ';
$replace[] = 'സാ';

$malayalam_string = str_replace($search, $replace, $english_string);

echo $malayalam_string //സാആസാ
```